# Android: using Google sign in to get access token

Tags: android, google-plus

After reading the last Google + news at [here](http://allthingsd.com/20130226/with-new-sign-in-feature-google-plus-makes-its-developer-pitch/) and [this](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in). How do I get access token after I complete the sign in?

Answer (score 4):

To answer doubts about oauth scope (just to be useful for googlers):

To fully understand, Google-it some about authentication and authorization concepts.

Check if user/password exists is about **authentication** part.

Scope is required to **authorization** part: what you are authorized to do or receive in behalf of user. To get a list of scopes allowed, check the OAuth service documentation.

From Google and G+, most common scopes can be found on: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth?hl=pt-ZA

For example, to get all possible information from user, you can use the scope:

"openid profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"

(the first word refer to protocol, followed by words that ask for fields on response, and desired scopes can be declared toghether with a space separator)

**Note: Later, if you try use your access token to request or do anything that you don't asked before with a scope, the service can return an authorization error.**

For Google, a good tool you can use to learn about his OAuth service and scope is the OAuth Playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Answer (score 3):

Did you have a look at the [API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html)?

The class you are probably looking for is [`com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html).

It provides, amongst others, the following method:
[`static String getToken(Context context, String accountName, String`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

**Description:**
Authenticates the user and returns a valid Google authentication token, or throws an exception if there was an error getting a token.

**Usage:**

```
String token;
try {
    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountName, scope);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException playEx) {
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
        playEx.getConnectionStatusCode(),
        Activity.this,
        AUTH_REQUEST_CODE);
    // Use the dialog to present to the user.
} catch (UserRecoverableAutException recoverableException) {
    Intent recoveryIntent = recoverableException.getIntent();
    // Use the intent in a custom dialog or just startActivityForResult.
} catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
    // This is likely unrecoverable.
    Log.e(TAG, "Unrecoverable authentication exception: " + authEx.getMesssage(), authEx);
} catch (IOException ioEx) {
    Log.i(TAG, "transient error encountered: " + ioEx.getMessage());
    doExponentialBackoff();
}
```

Comment: This [link](https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/9607551) explains how exactly token should be fetched. Wrap those code in an async task.

Comment: @arefin is account name refers to email id in the given link?

Comment: @VivekPratapSingh Yes. If you are talking about lines 36, 44, 52, 60, and 64, then yes they represent the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch it using async task.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // Reaching onConnected means we consider the user signed in.
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");

    // Update the user interface to reflect that the user is signed in.
    mSignInButton.setEnabled(false);
    mSignOutButton.setEnabled(true);
    mRevokeButton.setEnabled(true);

    // Retrieve some profile information to personalize our app for the user.
    Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);


    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String > task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = null;
            final String SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login ";

            try {
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                         getApplicationContext(),
                         Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),
                         "oauth2:" + SCOPES);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


          return token;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + token);
        }

    };
    task.execute();


    System.out.print("email" + email);
    mStatus.setText(String.format(
            getResources().getString(R.string.signed_in_as),
            currentUser.getDisplayName()));

    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null)
            .setResultCallback(this);

    // Indicate that the sign in process is complete.
    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
}
```

Your access token will be stored into token variable.